# Dirvish, include a path in backup, work around

Tags: backup

Dirvish is explained in many places in internet. Here's one:
https://www.funtoo.org/Package:Dirvish_Backup

In the master.conf -file the path to exclude is written. But is there a neat way or a work around to include a specific path!?

I did not find any information when searching and my imagination is not wide enough to bring me a relevant answer...

Is there a way to include a path in the backup?

Example:
Backup include, but only this file, not the rest!
/srv/backup/server1/dirvish/dirvish.conf
/srv/backup/server2/dirvish/dirvish.conf
/srv/backup/server3/dirvish/dirvish.conf
/srv/backup/server4/dirvish/dirvish.conf
/srv/backup/server5/dirvish/dirvish.conf

Along side the path, "/srv/backup/dirvish", all the backups is stored as folders with dates, such as 20230810 as of today.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Copy&paste your configuration file and format it as a code block, e.g. by using the `{}` tool of the editor field. Show the commands you run with their output, if applicable. Show an example of the paths you want to exclude or include matching the configuration file.

Comment: Reading the documentation, it appears that all folders under the `tree` parameter are backed up. You don't seem to be able to enter multiple `tree` parameters, so you would need to create a different config file for each path.